# MS Access connected to SQL Server backend over wan?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I need to develop a database that will have users scattered around the world (around 50 users total, but not simultaneous).  I have two questions:

1) I know that with an Access front end connected to an Access back end I risk corruption over a wan, but is that still a risk using sql server?

2) If corruption is not a risk, will performance still make Access an undesirable choice for a front end?

Users will primarily be adding anywhere from 200-800 new records at a time.

Any advice on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The team I work with has taken a variety of approaches to solving the problem you describe. Web apps connecting to a SQL Server back end, .NET desktop apps connection to a SQL Server back end, and MS Access apps, connecting to both SQL Server and MS Access back ends.

In terms of your two specific questions, here are my thoughts based on recent experience.

Question 1) I know that with an Access front end connected to an Access back end I risk corruption over a wan, but is that still a risk using SQLserver?

Answer 1) No. Unlike Access, SQL Server is a robust multi-user database management system. It handles multi-user access and preserves database integrity. You can build your app by creating linked tables in your Access database pointing to their counterpart tables in your SQL Server database. After that, code your Access application as you normally would.

Question 2) If corruption is not a risk, will performance still make Access an undesirable choice for a front end?

Answer 2) My experience is that when accessing a SQL Server back end using linked tables in Access, performance optimization is difficult. Mainly because Access makes decisions about how much data to pull across the network and when to do that. You can't control those things programatically yourself in the same ways you can with the data access objects available in web or .NET desktop apps. Access databases are also logistically more difficult to deploy and maintain (particularly in comparison to a web app), and they are dependent on the version of Access that is installed on your users' workstations.

Hope it helps. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be worried about corrupted data when using SQL server as the back-end. Though you should still be concerned with backups, admin requirements, etc.

Re: Access as a front end. Actually works fairly well as long as you ignore deployment issues. Pushing out updates to multiple workstations can be a real pain, and the Access App itself is pretty finicky to install.

Lots of people write a web-app these days for applications just like this. If you don't want to write a web-app, a dot.net based smart client app is a popular choice too.

What is likely important is what expertise is available, how good is the support, how much it costs, etc. Pretty much any popular technology stack will work with enough TLC.

Also don't overlook getting a canned application that already does what you need.